# How to get the file name from an RRQ datagramPacket?

Tags: java, sockets, server, datagram, tftp

Im working on a TFTP server. Basing on the image the max length of my packets is 516 bytes (2+2+512).

I'm trying to take the original length from the client datagrampacket(in this case sends 13 bytes in a RRQ packet), instead im getting the server datagrampacket length (516 bytes) where i save the client datagrampacket.

I need that for extract the filename, i did that but the string content is "filename + nullBytes", those null bytes come from the server datagrampacket.

This is the code where im stuck:

```
public static short RRQ = 1;
        enter code here
    public void dataMetod() throws IOException{
                        byte[] packet = new byte[516];
                        //socket with listening port 5000
                        DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(5000);

                    //while receive packets
                    while (true) {
                    DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new  DatagramPacket(packet,packet.length);
                    datagramSocket.receive(datagramPacket);
                    System.out.println("server: new packet!!:");

                    //create a byte[] with the "received packet length"(that's not true)
                    byte[] inData = new byte[datagramPacket.getLength()];
                    inData = datagramPacket.getData();

                    System.out.println("length: "+inData.length);
                    byte code;
                    code = inData[1];
                    System.out.println(code);

                    //check if its an RRQ packet
                    if (code == RRQ) {
                        System.out.println("server: RRQ PACKET!!");
                        String fileName = this.getFileName(inData);
                        System.out.println(fileName);


                }

public String getFileName(byte[] inData) {
        byte[] aux = new byte[inData.length - 7];
        for (int i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) {
            aux[i] = inData[i + 2];
        }
        return new String(aux);
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dTH6.png

Comment: How do you know the client actually only sent 13 bytes? What client are you using?

Comment: OK, sorry its my first post,  working on it.

Comment: TFTP says "the filename is null-terminated". Maybe you should rely on just that.

Comment: "the filename is null-terminated" becuase of the packet length, so i rely on that.

Comment: No, the filename is terminated by a single 0x00, then comes the "mode" and another 0x00. The spec says nothing about "the last seven bytes in a packet". (mode can also be "netascii"...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public String getFileName(byte[] inData) {

    final int maxLen = inData.length;

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int i = 2;
    byte b;

    while ( (i < maxLen) && (b = inData[i]) != 0 ) {
        final int v = ((int)b) & 0xff;
        sb.append( (char) v );
        i++;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Its says:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: null address || null buffer

Comment: I tried something like search the index of byte(0+mode+0) patron in inData (with Arrays.binarySearch()), maybe there is a way with that , but I didnt arrive to get the original length.

Comment: I thought about writing an if() which compares with null bytes and return the string at the 1st null byte it founds, but i didn't find  a comparation with null bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the original length of the received packet(to search the file name through the array), we could do that by adding "\n" at fileName String in client class, then use BufferedReader which will detect "\n" and save the fileName.
Code:

```
    public String getFileName(byte[] inData) throws IOException {

    //get a sub-array, from index[2] (beacuse we dont want opCode) to inData length

        byte[] b =Arrays.copyOfRange(inData, 2, inData.length);

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    //We read a word that will be saved when "\n" is found.
    //(adding "\n" previously to the fileName String in client class)

        String filename = bf.readLine();
        bf.close();
        is.close();
        System.out.println("server: filename is: "+filename.length()+" bytes");
        return filename;
}
```